# running grails unit tests in vim

Tags: testing, grails, vim

Im trying to find a way to run my grails unit/integration tests in vim without having to leave my editor. Is there a good plugin for that? I took a lot of tips from here http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/02/21/using-vim-as-your-grails-ide-part-1-navigating-your-project/ but I dont want to have to switch to just see the output.

I tried it with a keymap but grails has to start up each time. Any ideas? How do you guys do this?

I also found this https://github.com/hoffoo/vim-grails-console but couldn't get it set up properly.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "couldn't get it set up properly" mean? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: I couldn't install it - it said I need python support. Im running Debian, looks like I first need to compile vim myself. Ill try that

Comment: Install the `vim-gtk` package if you run a graphical desktop environment or `vim-nox` if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I've started to use Tim Pope's [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin to execute tests in a shell and then report the results back to vim.  You can see my version of executing a grails test in my dotfiles repo, specifically, in [grailsScripts](https://github.com/sjurgemeyer/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/plugin/grailsScripts.vim)

In order for the plugin to report back to vim, you need to set an errorformat.  I've battled with vim's errorformat for quite awhile and ultimately landed on using a combination of reformatting the output with a groovy script and using errorformat to highlight file paths.  The result is that you see the entire grails output in the error list, but can hit enter on lines with file paths and go to the line in question.  It's not perfect, but it works.

If you are interested in using that method, you'll want to also get the following files from my dotfiles:

- .vim/tools/filters.groovy
- .vim/compiler/grails.vim

Note that these scripts work in my setup, but I haven't made them into a plugin yet, so your mileage may vary.  I hope it helps!